# Watch SQL running queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

Watch the Performance of running queries specially on large sets of data Insertion or similar queries.

**As an example :**

What could be an option if you are going to Select-Insert a quite simple query on about millions of records

Is there an option for using a CountDown performance timer to see how much time each thousands records is taking ?

Code-Based practices or Tool-Based practices

What do you suggest ?

*Any piece of information regarding these is appreciated.*

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon: What happened to your counting abilities

Comment: There may be some tools or techniques that target the whole idea, because of that I had an eye on if there were be a generic solution, on the other hand any pieces of practices regarding looking the execution flow performance is the more specific goal we are looking for. e.g If I mentioned logging again I meant performance related logging or the execution flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably aren't going to be able to analyze how long each 1k records takes to insert on the fly unless you build in a mechanism to give you feedback into your query.  I.e. you could do a loop and do it in batches of 1k records, or you could maybe do select statements from another thread periodically to do a count on the table and see the difference although my attempts at that method have not always worked perfectly.

If you want a better profiler (in my opinion) than the one that comes with SQL Server, you can get one for free here: http://anjlab.com/en/projects/opensource/sqlprofiler.  The great thing about this profiler is that you can actually sort the results as they are still coming in, which you can't do with Microsoft's profiler.  I used this a lot at my last job to identify places in our app where we weren't caching data and were needlessly running the same queries over and over again.

Comment: I should be agree with you in logic, cause I will do the same while coding, Could you please give a simple pattern-based code on this kind of observation in sql.

Comment: +1: IIRC, SQL operations like INSERT and SELECT are inherently atomic - they either happen or they don't. If you're doing an insert of a batch of records, I don't think there's a consistent & accurate way to  determine 'X% of operation complete' because of that basic principle of atomic...ness.

Comment: @mikurski Haha, yeah that's prolly why my attempt to do my second suggestion didn't work too well for me.  It guess it would only work if the records are being submitted 1 at a time (or in batches).  Now I feel kinda dumb for not realizing that before :)

Comment: @mikurski agree, I think at first I didn't ask the question the correct way. This is the way I should go.

Comment: @mikurski Really depends how you're doing it.  Are you trying to do it as pure sql or can you use c#?  The basic idea though is to partition (split up) the data you're wanting to insert.  Basically you're going to order your data somehow (let's say you have a field called AutoNumberId) and select the top 1000 rows to insert; then you give yourself some feedback on how long it took; then you find out what the largest AutoNumberId is that you just inserted and then you get the next top 1000 where AutoNumberId is greater than the greatest one you've already inserted and then repeat.

Comment: @BrandonMoore: If you can partition it so each batch is a subgrouping of the entire set you're working with? Yeah, I've had cases where I've been inserting a single record at a time for a large set of records, then just doing a `COUNT(*)` on the primary table for the inserts to get a feel for how much is being done.

The only thing there is that you're moving away from set-based operations and into iteration, which can be unoptimal for SQL. You can measure how long something takes, at the cost of making it take longer. It's a quantum thing. ;)

Comment: @mikurski Oops, actually that comment was just supposed to be an answer to Sypress's request for me to give an example rather than a reply to your comment but I accidently tagged you instead of him :)  You are exactly right.  The idea would be to do large batches so that you can see maybe something like every 10% of the way but not so often that it has a significant impact on performance.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Profiler will give you a detailed breakdown on the resource consumption of the individual SQL statements you are running.  SSMS's "Show Execution Plan" option will break down individual SQL statements and show you the internal details on how SQL Server is choosing to optimize your statements.

If I understand you correctly (and I'm not sure I do), you're probably best off using Profiler to track general performance.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the info, Saying Profiler is too general to find the piece of information I'm looking for, I edited the topic to address my need more specific. +1